# Why the output is not displayed with a new variable?

Tags: php, function, echo, global

Why output ($h) not displayed?
I don't want to delete (function)

please correct it.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$x = 5 . "*";
$y = 10 . "=";

function myTest() {
    global $x, $y;
    $h = $x + $y; //new variable
} 
myTest();  // run function

echo $x . $y . $h; // output the value 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$h` only has scope inside the `test` function. To get the `$h` value, you could either make `$h` global, or preferably return the value from the myTest function.

**Note:** the function should normally be a self-contained unit. By giving globals scope inside the function (using `global $x, $y`) introduces un-needed and possibly harmful dependencies to code. The code below is an example only to illustrate the solution to your question.

```
function myTest() {
    global $x, $y;
    return $x + $y;
} 

$h = myTest();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use variable `$h` as global variable

```
$x = 5 . "*";
$y = 10 . "=";
$h = null;// declare $h
function myTest() {
  global $x, $y, $h; //use $h here
  $h = $x + $y; //new variable
} 
myTest();  // run function

echo $x . $y . $h; // output the value
```